# Python GET request error 405 : needs cookie header

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, python-requests

I need to get some data on a web page with Python using the requests module.

Everything goes well with my Firefox web browser : I can get the web page with all the data displayed.

So first attempt :

```
request = requests.get(url)
print(request)
```

I got Response [405]...

After some request analysis with the Firefox network monitor, I isolated that the GET request needs a cookie.

So, second attempt :

```
header = {
'Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=...'
}
second_request = requests.get(url, headers=header)
print(second_request)
```

This time, I got Response [200]. All is OK...

The 'Cookie' header has been poorly copied from the Firefox network monitor (headers analysis).

My question is : I would like to automate the process of obtaining this cookie. Do you know how I could do that please ?

Thank you for your support, regards.

Comment: You essentially need to log in via `requests`. Do you log in to this site via a traditional login form?

Comment: No log in. Just visiting the web page.

Comment: Can you provide the URL?

Comment: https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/Linx-Technologies/ANT-868-SP?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsgSGrx0WqTbJiXY09TWm57

Comment: it is tough to crawl website even use `selenium`. Because it applys a complex way to verify your browser.